# Do-while or while loop to use math.random to generate a set of 20 numbers

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is generate a set of 20 different random numbers, then display the average, number of positive numbers and number of negative numbers. I'm stumped on generating the set of numbers to use, but I think I have everything else done right.

```
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;
int count = 0;
int total = 0;
int average;


Random r = new Random();
int number = 0;


 while (count > 20) {
    number = r.nextInt(200);
    total += number;
    count++;
    if (number > 0) {
        positive++;
    } 
    else if (number < 0) {
        negative++;
    }
}
average = (double) total / count;
System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive + " ");
System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative + " ");
System.out.printf("The average is: " + average);
```

Comment: `while ((number = r.nextInt(150)-67) != 0)` how is this suppose to know when to stop at 20?r

Comment: What do you expect `while (count >= 66)` to do?

Comment: i see your edit... why not lets try... `while(count < 60)`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's working because its not grabbing more than 1 positive or negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you to total up 20 random numbers from 0-100 and then display the result.

```
private int total = 0;
private int i = 0;
private Random generator = new Random();
private int pos = 0;
private int neg = 0;
private int max_int = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private int min_int = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int x;    

while(i < 20){
    x = (int) int val = 100 - generator.nextInt(200);

    if(x > max_int)
        max_int = x;
    if(x < min_int)
        min_int = x;

    if(x >= 0)
        pos ++;
    else 
        neg ++;

    total += x
    i++;
}

System.out.println(total / 20.0);
System.out.println("Positive number count :: " + pos);
System.out.println("Positive number count :: " + neg);
System.out.println("Max :: " + max_int);
System.out.println("Min :: " + min_int);
```

Comment: When I run it, I'm getting

Comment: 'code' 
6.35
The number of positives is 1 
The number of negatives is 0 
The largest number is: 0. And the smallest number is: 0.
The average is: Infinity

Comment: Thank you for getting me to understand this, and on a side note, what about adding in the min and max, with the averages for both? My idea is ' if (x > max){
      max = x;
      averageMax = max/positive;
     }
     if (x < min) {
      min = x;
      averageMin = min/negative;
     }
 }'

Comment: i don't know what you mean by averages for the max and the min but i updated the code so it has a max and a min. If this answers your question please accept the answer

Comment: The average for the negative and positive number set is what I was trying to say.